# How to sync "for" loop counter in multithread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, synchronization, critical-section

How to sync "for" loop counter on multithread?

If these multi thread program

```
void Func(int n){
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ //at the same time with other Func()
  cout << i <<endl;
 }
}

void main(){
 std::thread t1(Func(2));
 std::thread t2(Func(2));
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
}
```

When executing Func() in parallel , I want to sync "for" loop counter "i".

For example, the program has possibility to output the result

```
0
1
0
1
```

but I want to always get the result

```
0
0
1
1
```

Can I it?

Comment: Your program has the possibility to print other things too (like `00`) also.  How do you want the counter synced?  Do you want to always guarantee the log messages are printed in order?  If so, why do you want multiple threads?

Comment: This is simplified program for ask question. My original program is simulating multi agent system (Distributed Stochastic Algorithm). In the original program, I want to sync number of trials of all agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use a few variables for the threads to coordinate things (in the following they are globals, just for simplicity).

```
mutex m;
condition_variable c;
static int index = 0;
static int count = 2;
```

The `index` variable says at which index are the threads, and the `count` variable says how many threads are at the index still.

Now you're loop becomes:

```
void Func(int n){
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ //at the same time with other Func()
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    c.wait(l, [i](){return index == i;});
    cout << i <<endl;
    if(--count == 0)
    {
        ++index;
        count = 2;
        c.notify_one();
    }
 }
}
```

---

Here is the full code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


mutex m;
condition_variable c;
static int index = 0;
static int count = 2;


void Func(int n){
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ //at the same time with other Func()
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    c.wait(l, [i](){return index == i;});
    cout << i <<endl;
    if(--count == 0)
    {
        ++index;
        count = 2;
        c.notify_one();
    }
 }
}


int main(){
 std::thread t1(Func, 20);
 std::thread t2(Func, 20);
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use OpenMP to thread your loop you can use a `#pragma omp barrier` statement.

In C++11 you can use a [condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to block all threads until they reach the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`std:atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) variable and pass it to all threads.

```
void Func(int n, int & i){
    for (; i<n; i++){ //at the same time with other Func()
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}

void main(){
    std::atomic<int> counter = 0;
    std::thread t1(Func, 2, std::ref(counter));
    std::thread t2(Func, 2, std::ref(counter));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Also you should note that the way you are crating your threads in your example are incorrect.  Secondly if you are using `cout` in multiple threads each `cout` should be guarded with a `std::mutex` as `cout` is not thread safe.